# Java API in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, api

Im new to eclipse , can anybody tell me how to use an JAVA API in eclipse. or share any sample Java API.

Yes, how to use JavaDoc file in eclipse.

Comment: Do you mean how to import and use classes from the standard Java packages?

Comment: do you mean to ask, how to open javadoc from within Eclipse IDE?

Comment: can you clarify the question please?

Comment: Let's see, "Is the question unclear or not useful".  Hmm, pretty much the definition of unclear--check!

Comment: I want to know how to use an Java API in eclipse IDE. We want to build a framework using eclipse,so there are some API which we want to use in Eclipse IDE. how to use it.

Comment: Is this API a Jar which someone else wrote? Is it an open source project? Is the the _Eclipse API_ , that is are you writing an Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 7):

***Yes, how to use JavaDoc file in eclipse.***

You can download the Javadoc jar file from the respective project and include it in your build path

Eclipse==> project-->properties-->Java Build Path-->click on the jar file--> edit JavaDoc

Point it to the API URL location/Downloaded Jar file,

Typically, shift + F2 opens the API when the class is focussed upon

Comment: its same as using a plugin which is as a jar file.

Comment: This is the way JavaDoc is configured from eclipse IDE

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean: how to use a third-party Java library in your Java project in Eclipse?

Right-click your project in the Package Explorer and choose Properties. Go to "Java Build Path". Click "Add JARs" or "Add External JARs" to add the JAR file(s) of the library to your project.

"Add JARs" is for adding JAR files that are in your project directory. "Add External JARs" is for adding JAR files that are not in your project.

Note that the Eclipse help (Help / Help Contents) contains a lot of information, including information on how to work with Java projects in Eclipse and how to add libraries to your Java project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear exactly what you're after, but if you create a new Java project, you will have access to the JRE system library's contents as a classpath container.

**File**->**New**->**Java Project**, enter project name, select **OK**.

You'll then be able to create new classes and access the Java classes.

If you want to reference another jar containing the "API", you can add it to the project's build path.

Say the jar is in the "lib" folder of your project, open the project properties (<kbd>alt+enter</kbd>), the Select **Java Build Path**, then the **Libraries** tab, select **Add JARs...**, then browse to the lib folder and select the jar you want to add and select OK.

To attach sources and javadoc to the jar, you can expand the selector in the Libraries tab, click on **Source attachment** and **Edit...** and browse to the location of the sources jar/zip, repeat for the Javadoc. The screenshot below shows you the Source attachment option for rt.jar

[image: Libraries screenshot]
<sub>(source: [vogella.de](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/images/add_source_to_jar.jpg))</sub>

and ok back to the workbench.

You should now see that the jar is included on the project's path (the jar has a little overlaid icon on it).

If this is not what you're after, can you rephrase the question?

Comment: in the Java project which i create i want to use an API. how do i use it

Comment: Thank you. I could understand that adding an API is same as using a plugin which is also as a jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some nice [Eclipse video tutorials](http://jonah.cs.elon.edu/dpowell2/Courses/EclipseTutorial/EclipseTutorial.htm) . The version of Eclipse is dated ( 3.1 ), but the concepts are still there.

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is to hover mouse over some in-built method or class that are using in your program. Hold ctrl on your keyboard and click. Then eclipse asks you to attach source. click on 'attach source', browse for src.zip file after choosing 'EXTRENAL' file. or instead give path for extracted src folder under same ie external file attachment. Next time you hover over an in-built class or method it shows a small description. To view entire javadoc for same, keep holding ctrl and click on it.        It worked for me.